# Can not get background color in PDF generated from HTML

Tags: php, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I am using following code to generate PDf from HTML I have but I am not getting the background color as is in HTML provided. I get a white background.

```
$content = "
<html>
<body bgcolor='#E6E45A'>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>";
     require_once('html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php');
    try
    {
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        $html2pdf->Output('exemple01.pdf','D');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
```

How can this be achieved in **html2pdf** that I am using.

**Added:**

It does however support  tag and backcolor='#AAAACC' inside it is working. But I need some thing more widely accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the library doesn't recognize the deprecated `bgcolor` attribute. Try the style attribute instead.

```
$content = '
<html>
<body style="background: #E6E45A;">
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: It does not support that either. It does however support <page> tag and backcolor='#AAAACC' inside it is working. But I need some thing more widely accepted.

Comment: I've found http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ to be a great solution for converting all sorts of webpages to PDF.

Comment: Yes am looking at it and so far I have not been able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Reference **exemple08.php** and you'll notice:

```html
<page backcolor="#48626f" style="">
    <!-- // rest of the page HTML in here -->
</page>
```